# ImageView not populating from file path

Tags: android

I can't get my ImageViews to update from either URI or file path - they just don't show an image

Intent to capture image:

```
Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(photo, 1);
```

On ActivityResult

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri imageUri = data.getData();
    filePath = getRealPathFromURI(this, imageUri);
}
```

GetRealPathFromURI class:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It then inserts 'filePath' from onActivityResult in to a db

Retrieving from db and updating ImageViews

```
imgfilepath[y] = cursorc.getString(cursorc.getColumnIndex("IMAGE"));
imgFile[y] = new File(imgfilepath[y]);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imgFile[y]);
String path = uri.getPath();
mImage.setImageURI(uri);
```

I've tried so many different ways to setImageBitmap etc which haven't worked (I can't remember all of them) - Can anyone see why this is not showing the image?

The image is in emulated storage and not the SD card.

EDIT:

I've added EXTRA_OUTPUT tag but I can't see the image in DDMS anywhere & the camera does not exit after taking the picture/accepting the image

```
Intent photo = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyDir" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            final String fname = "img_"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
            mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
            photo.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);
            startActivityForResult(photo, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri imageUri = data.getData();
```

`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` does not return a `Uri`.

> The image is in emulated storage

Perhaps that one camera app does, in which case that camera app has a bug, to go along with the return-a-`Uri` bug.

There are thousands of Android device models. These ship with hundreds of different camera apps pre-installed, and there are hundreds more available from the Play Store and elsewhere. Many will have `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` implementations. Most should follow [the documented protocol](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). None should save the image for your request, because you did not tell the camera app where to save the image.

Either:

- Provide a location, via `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, for the camera app to save the image to, then load the image from that location, or
- Use `data.getExtra("data")` to get a `Bitmap` that represents a thumbnail-sized image, if you do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT`

Comment: Since I've implemented the EXTRA_OUTPUT the camera does not allow me to confirm the picture, only cancel or retake. The tick icon is there but doesn't do anything

Comment: @RJH94: There is no requirement that a camera app allow the user to confirm the picture when launched by `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

Comment: I'll update the question with my new code, it doesn't seem to be returning an image, I can't see it in DDMS

Comment: @RJH94: "I've added EXTRA_OUTPUT tag but I can't see the image in DDMS anywhere" -- then presumably you are working with an exceptionally buggy camera app. Camera apps vary in quality, and some have exhibited these sorts of problems. [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not reliable](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html). Either gracefully fail in these cases (and suggest to the user that they should download some better camera app), or start using the camera APIs yourself to take pictures directly.